# Duplicate Spotlight

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a photo blog, and I'm working on a slightly different idea but and I've got this neat spotlight to work, however trying to duplicate it to make more than one neat little spotlight won't seem to work.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/1.2/base.min.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

   <div class="main">
    <ul>
     <li><div class="tjena"><img class="bild" src="http://i.imgur.com/GocRzkn.jpg" alt="" /></div></li>
     <li><img class="bild" src="http://i.imgur.com/GocRzkn.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>

   </div>
 <div id="overlag 1"> 
  <div id="spotlight" class="spotlight"></div>
 </div>

 <div id="overlag 2">
  <div id="spotlight" class="spotlight"></div>
 </div>
 <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/okfocus/okshadow/master/src/okshadow.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  background-image: url("http://www.wildtextures.com/wp-content/uploads/wildtextures_white-brick-wall.jpg");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: 30%;
}

.main {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.main .title {
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.main .sub-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
.main ul {
  display: flex;
}
.main ul li {
  margin: 0 120px;
}

.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, circle cover, transparent -7%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 13%);
}
.bild {
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Define "won't seem to work"?

Comment: Sorry, should off sent the codepen straight up http://codepen.io/jcedborger/pen/KargxG

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Comment: @TiesonT. Tried just duplicating it straight off by making two and giving them two different locations on the screen, I also tried creating two and gave them the same class, however separating the two completely.

Comment: @j08691 Ohh yea, completely missed that. Don't reckon it'll change anything however.

Comment: you can use multiple background-image, duplicate your first radial-gradient to many others with differents size/position : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OpdEpr